# django has created problem page not found when i use dynamic url

Tags: django

app/urls.py

```
        from django.conf.urls import url
        from . import views
        urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.home, name = "home"),
        url(r'^productform/', views.product_create_view,   name="productform"),
        url(r'^products/<int:id>', views.products, name="products"),
                ]
```

root/urls.py

```
      from django.conf.urls import url, include
      from django.contrib import admin

      urlpatterns = [
      url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
      url(r'', include('firstapp.urls')),
           ]
```

views.py--->>

```
         def products(request, id):
         obj = Product.objects.get(id=id)
         context = {
                "objects":obj
            }
         return render(request, "firstapp/products.html", context)
```

getting page not found error

i am getting this error on my browser
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0eqx.png)

Comment: A common error: you mix `path(..)` syntax with `url(..)` syntax.

Comment: may you elaborate this please @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 1):

Your `url(..)` contains [**`path(..)`** syntax [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#path). You can fix the problem by using `path(..)` ([django-2.0](/questions/tagged/django-2.0) and higher); or by converting the pattern to a regex-pattern and use [**`url(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#url) or [**`re_path(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#path) ([django-2.0](/questions/tagged/django-2.0) and higher).

So in [django-2.0](/questions/tagged/django-2.0) and higher, we can fix the problem by writing:

```
from django.conf.urls import path, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name = "home"),
    url(r'^productform/', views.product_create_view,   name="productform"),
    path('products/<int:id>', views.products, name="products"),
]
```

or in [django-1.x](/questions/tagged/django-1.x):

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name = "home"),
    url(r'^productform/', views.product_create_view,   name="productform"),
    url(r'^products/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.products, name="products"),
]
```